# Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, sql-insert

```
const res = await this.callApi('post','place_order',this.formItem)
if(res.status == 200){
                this.order.push(res.data)
                this.s("Order Successful !")
                this.formItem = {}
}
```

When I received the response from controller this showing me 'push' is undefined.

And this is my controller

```
public function place_order(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();
        $order= Order::create($data);

        return response()->json([
            'order' => $order,
            'success' => true
        ],200);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the type of "this.order". [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) will only work on arrays.

Edit: Since that it says that "push 'of' undefined", you should also check if "this.order" is really defined.